# Error when setting animation TriggerShape for an audio shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Prerequisites for the code snippets below:

1. A basic shape named "Shape"
2. A basic shape named "Trigger"
3. An audio object shape named "Audio"
4. All of the above are on Slide 1

When I run code to add an animation effect for a shape based on another trigger shape being clicked, it works correctly:

```
Dim sld as Slide
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

With sld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add

   With .AddEffect(sld.Shapes("Shape"), msoAnimEffectAppear, , msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
      .Timing.TriggerShape = sld.Shapes("Trigger")
   End With

End With
```

**Outcome:** an 'appear' animation is added with a trigger of the "Trigger" shape

However if I try the same where the shape is an audio object with a play / pause / stop animation effect I get an error:

```
Dim sld as Slide
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

With sld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add

   With .AddEffect(sld.Shapes("Audio"), msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
      .Timing.TriggerShape = sld.Shapes("Trigger")
   End With

End With
```

**Outcome**: Run-time error (below). A 'play' animation is added but the trigger is the "Audio" shape itself (which is the default behaviour) not the "Trigger" shape.

> Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)':
>   Timing (unknown member) : Invalid request.

It seems as though you can't get or set the `TriggerShape` (or the `Timing` object) with VBA.

I can change the trigger shape manually via the UI dropdown directly as usual but trying to access it with VBA just returns the error.

If I add the audio animation *after* a regular shape in the sequence, there's no need to specify the `TriggerShape` again and the animation is correctly added under the same trigger, which is a workaround.

But it seems as though adding an audio shape as the first animation in the sequence with a trigger shape isn't possible unless I'm doing something wrong?

Using PowerPoint for Mac Version 16.35 (20030802)

Comment: As posted, neither of your snippets run in PowerPoint for Windows. Both report the same problem: Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Item Trigger not found in the Shapes collection.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned some prerequisites for those snippets were:
1. A basic shape named "Shape"
2. A sound object shape named "Audio"
3. A basic shape named "Trigger"

The code obviously doesn't create any of these and that error just indicates the shape named "Trigger" can't be found on the slide I think.

Comment: For me, the 1st snippet correctly adds an appear animation for the shape named "Shape" with a trigger of the shape named "Trigger". The 2nd snippet results in the run-time error mentioned in the description – the 'Timing' part of the effect object doesn't seem to exist or be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

For an ordinary shape, '.Timing.TriggerShape = triggerShape' will work. But, for a media type, you'd better use 'AddTriggerEffect' instead.

In your situation, the code snippet would go like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim eft As Effect
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    
    With sld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add
    
        'Below is OK but, instead, you can use AddTriggerEffect for triggered animation effects.
        'Set eft = .AddEffect(sld.Shapes("Shape"), msoAnimEffectAppear, , msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
        'eft.Timing.TriggerShape = sld.Shapes("Trigger")
        Set eft = .AddTriggerEffect(sld.Shapes("Shape"), msoAnimEffectAppear, _
                                    msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick, sld.Shapes("Trigger"))
        eft.Timing.Duration = 0.5
    
        '//first, added as a trigger effect to be run 'onClick'
        Set eft = .AddTriggerEffect(sld.Shapes("Audio"), msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, _
                                    msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick, sld.Shapes("Trigger"))
        '//then, change the effect to be run 'WithPrevious'
        eft.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Notice that following code will not work. So I split it into two steps.

```
    Set eft = .AddTriggerEffect(sld.Shapes("Audio"), msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, _
                                msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious, sld.Shapes("Trigger"))
    '//Above will not work
```

With this code, when you click on the 'Trigger' shape, the 'Shape' will appear while playing the 'Audio' at the same time.